# How to change "WriteAllLines" data type in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, io

I'm trying to find the **union** between two files. 
When I first ran the program the information becomes formatted to `concat` style which just combines the two files. So I assume it's due to it being string variable that I'm not able to find the union between the files. I tried to change it `double` and `int` and it didn't work. (Most likely I don't know how to properly do it)

Text from first files :

```
1
2
3
4444
5555
6666
```

Text from second file:

```
1
2
3
7777
8888
9999
```

Desired output based on that input :

```
1
2
3
```

this should be displayed in the datagridview box since it's the only numbers that are common between the files.

It's way more numbers (10,000 to be exact). I union the data then went into bin and Ctrl+F the txt from notepad and couldn't find any similarities amongst information. Yet it still produced an output. I was thinking it would display a blank .txt file if the system couldn't find something common between the files, but I could be wrong.

```
    Dim firstFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Random_Numbers_One.txt")
    Dim secondFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Random_Numbers_Two.txt")

    IO.File.WriteAllLines("Union.txt", firstFile.Union(secondFile))
    Dim fileUnion() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Union.txt")
    Dim format = From Numbers In fileUnion
                 Let data = Numbers.Split(","c)
    dgvThree.DataSource = format.ToList
```

Comment: just you want to combine two list and remove duplicate numbers ? is it true?

Comment: it's work correctly! what is your problem actually? please write problem code place

Comment: Show sample text from files.

Comment: Please show samples of your input files and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I see your edit. You need to also show the expected output, and with that in mind much smaller samples will work better. Just tthe first 5 numbers per file (with a contrived alteration so one of the numbers appears in both files), along with the expected output of that is plenty... small enough to work out the output by hand so we can see what you expect the algorithm to do.

Comment: "Desired output : 1,2,3 should be displayed in the datagridview box since it's the only numbers that are common between the files. " Getting people banned because they need help is really nice.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I saw it, deleting my comment.

Comment: No one gets banned because of one downvote... but for future reference, what you are asking for is **not** a union at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the intersection of the lists, not the union.

```
Dim firstFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Random_Numbers_One.txt")
Dim secondFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Random_Numbers_Two.txt")
dim common() as String = firstFile.Intersect(secondFile)
```

But if you also need the union of the two arrays, then:

```
dim allLines() as String = firstFile.Union(secondFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is **NOT** a union at all!  In relational data terms, a union of your sample data would look like this:

```
1
2
3
4444
5555
6666
7777
8888
9999
```

Which could also be expressed via FULL JOIN + COALESCE. Or you might get this if you meant a UNION ALL / Concatentation:

```
1
2
3
4444
5555
6666
1
2
3
7777
8888
9999
```

Neither of those are anywhere close to your expected output, which instead looks like the **intersection** of your data sets, also commonly called an INNER JOIN.

This can be accomplished in VB.Net with a single line of code:

```
dgvThree.DataSource = IO.File.ReadLines("Random_Numbers_One.txt").Intersect(IO.File.ReadLines("Random_Numbers_Two.txt"))
```

But to make it more readable:

```
dgvThree.DataSource = IO.File.ReadLines("Random_Numbers_One.txt").
            Intersect(IO.File.ReadLines("Random_Numbers_Two.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a shot. It should combine both lists and overlap on duplicates.

```
Dim firstFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Random_Numbers_One.txt")
 Dim secondFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Random_Numbers_Two.txt")
 Dim result() As String = firstFile.Concat(secondFile).Distinct().ToArray()
```